# Heroku Buildpack with Apache, PHP and Grunt

Tags: php, node.js, heroku, gruntjs

I use this Heroku Buildpack to compile my recent project on Heroku https://github.com/gcpantazis/heroku-buildpack-php-gruntjs

It works great with Node version 0.8.x. However, when I change to Node version 0.10.x and push code to heroku, it shows me this error "Failed to install -g grunt-cli --silent dependencies with npm".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the regular PHP and Node.js buildpacks using heroku-buildpack-multi. Example: http://heroku-multipack-nodejs-php-ex.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1):

We use two buildpacks to enable us to compile frontend assets with Grunt

`$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
 Buildpack set. Next release on your-application will use heroku/nodejs.
 Run git push heroku master to create a new release using this buildpack.
 $ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php --index 2
 Buildpack set. Next release on your-application will use:
   1. heroku/nodejs
   2. heroku/php
 Run git push heroku master to create a new release using these buildpacks.`